# How to remove button present in other section

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML .

```
<div id="restmenu" class="restMenu">
   <ul>

      <section id="LocationX" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit">LocationX<span class="inDelete"></span></div>
         <ul class="restListings">
            <div class="inner-intit">
               <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
               <li>
                  <h6>Swaghat</h6>
                  <p>MadhaPur , Near Policstation,Hyderabad</p>
                  <span class="inDelete inDeleteSub"></span>
               </li>
            </div>
            <input type="button" location="LocationX" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success addNewRestaurant" value="LocationX">
         </ul>
      </section>

      <section id="SoftSol" class="ulseWrap lielement">
         <div class="intit">SoftSol<span class="inDelete"></span></div>
         <ul class="restListings"><input type="button" location="LocationX" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success addNewRestaurant" value="LocationX"></ul>
      </section>

   </ul>
</div>
```

I need to remove the button present in SoftSol location

I tried it this way

```
var locationname = 'SoftSol';
$("#restmenu").find('section').not("#"+locationname).find('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
```

But its not removing the Button .

Could anybody please let me know whats the issue ?

I am still having problem , i couldn't able to remove Buttons present in other section with the name 
addNewRestaurant

This is my code

```
function showRestaurantDetailsByLocation(responseeee,locationname)
{

        var ulhtml = $('<ul class="restListings"></ul>'); 
        var divhtml = $('<div class="inner-intit"><sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub></div>'); 
        divhtml.append('<br>');
        for(var i=0;i<responseeee.length;i++)
        {
          divhtml.append('<li><h6>'+responseeee[i].name+'</h6><p>'+responseeee[i].address+'</p><span class="inDelete inDeleteSub"></span></li>'); 
        }
         ulhtml.append(divhtml);
        $('.restListings').empty();
           $("#"+locationname).append(ulhtml); 
           $("#restmenu").not("#"+locationname).find('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
var $newbutton= $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', location:locationname , name:'btn1', class:'btn btn-success addNewRestaurant',value:locationname});
        $('.restListings').append($newbutton);
        $(".restListings").show();
        $("#restmenu").show(); 
}
```

Comment: seems to be working - http://jsfiddle.net/rp7w40sL/, perhaps you didn't load jquery or you are running this code before the dom is loaded.

Comment: I see you also mentioned you want to remove the button in SoftSol, but it appears you are trying to remove all but the button in Softsol... if you want to remove the button in SoftSol, why not just `$("#"+locationname).find(".addNewRestaurant").remove();`?

Comment: It is working correctly. there is some other problem.

Comment: @afzalex It is removing a button, but I think he wants it to remove the other button.

Comment: @Dan, actually I'm thinking that was just a typo... but otherwise he could also just change the `locationname` to `LocationX`. I'm just assuming that he is wanting to remove all except a single button determined by `locationname`

Comment: @Dan , I need to remove the buttons , present in other sections , I have udated my question . please let me know whats wrong

Comment: Preethi, could you explain exactly what you want to happen and exactly what is happening (is any button getting removed? are you getting console errors? etc). Also, if you could put your dom/code in a jsfiddle, that would be nice.

Comment: @PreethiJain you are changing your HTML structure with your new code, this changes how you can find an element, thus the suggested answers don't work.

Comment: Still your question is not clear.. Do you want to remove the buttons, present in all sections other than `SoftSol`? Now I see you edited with different set of code. The suggested answers should work for your original question.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the button present in the `SoftSol` location do this:

```
$("#restmenu").find("#"+locationname).find('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
```

Currently you're using `not("#"+locationname)`, so it is removing the other button, and it will remove all other buttons with class `addNewRestaurant` that are within the `restmenu` element that are not in an element with `id=SoftSol`.

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rp7w40sL/1/)**

Comment: I am still having problem , i have updated my code , could you please let me know the issue ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var locationname = 'SoftSol';
$("#restmenu").find("#"+locationname).find('.addNewRestaurant').remove();
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rp7w40sL/3/)

Comment: This removes both buttons.